# Unity how to get result array in json?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, webapi

I want to get data from result and Total Row , but result cant defined it. But when I use api without array Result and TotalRow. I can use it with **allProduct[i].name_category** and direct to JsonClassPro. But now i want to use with array for make one API. Can anyone help ?

```
void DrawUI()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        GameObject goItems = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefabItems);
        goItems.transform.SetParent(ParentItems, false);
        goItems.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent <TMPro.TMP_Text>().text = allProduct.Result[i].name_category;
        goItems.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent <TMPro.TMP_Text>().text = allProduct.Result[i].name;
        goItems.transform.GetChild(3).GetComponent <TMPro.TMP_Text>().text = allProduct.Result[i].price.ToString();
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("IdProduct",allProduct[i].id_product);
        goItems.GetComponent<Button> ().AddEventListener(i, ItemClicked);
    }
}
```

API

[image: API]

Answer (score 0):

Install the Json.Newsoft package and import the reference to the package:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

Parse the Json string to a 'JObject' like such:

```
JObject? jsonObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

Then parse whatever value you want to an array because I don't know exactly what value you want parsed but i'll give you an example:

```
JArray? jsonArray = jsonObject["Result"].Value<JArray>();
```

Or you could do it this way:

```
IEnumerable<JObject?> results = jsonObject["Result"].Values<JObject>();
```